# Automatically email the Azure subscription cost analysis dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-automation

When you go to Subscription > Cost Analysis

There's a dashboard already set up. I recently found out my boss would "Download as .png" and email it to his boss every beginning of the month for the previous month. E.g. On Jan 4 2021 he emailed the .png of accumulated cost graphs for Dec 2020. When he told me he's been doing this for the past 5 months I said there's got to be a way to automate this...

I did search around to find that I can automatically export the data to an Azure Blob Storage and use logic apps to email it but I think my boss wants the graphs, the dashboard. Is there a way to automatically email the dashboard or maybe just the .png to my boss and his boss monthly?

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, in Azure Cost Management there is no notification system inbuilt which you can configure to send you weekly/monthly cost analysis email.

I would suggest you to vote up an idea submitted by another Azure customer.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/906772-cost-management/suggestions/36100237-email-custom-reports-on-a-schedule

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/906772-cost-management/suggestions/35308102-scheduled-dashboard-based-reports

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

**Alternate method:**

Here is an article which helps to send - [Weekly Azure billing report per mail with Azure functions](https://arminreiter.com/2017/09/weekly-azure-billing-report-per-mail-azure-functions/).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Azure has released this feature in Nov 2021.
You can read more on [Microsoft blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-cost-management-and-billing-updates-november-2021/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30724199)

Answer (score 0):

No. I'm afraid the answer is we can't export the data in graph/dashboard automatically.

If you still want this feature, you can create a ticket on azure [feedback page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).